# Should I use NodeJS(Express) web services between AngularJS app and SpringBoot WebServices?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, web-services, express, spring-boot

I am thinking about creating an app using AngularJS, NodeJS , and SpringBoot WebServices.

Should I use NodeJS(Express) web services between AngularJS app and SpringBoot WebServices ? If yes or no, please tell why.

Look forward to hearing your opinions !

AngularJS -> NodeJS(Express) -> SpringBoot WebServices -> DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `Javascript` is **NOT** `Java`.

It is rather strange to build your backend through two different kind of technologies. I would say you either go with just NodeJS (`Javascript`) or only SpringBoot (`Java`).

Building a server using NodeJS's `express` module as your middleware and then `SpringBoot` as your web service simply doesn't make sense to me... Unless you are saying you are intending to build a NodeJS application to act as a proxy server to talk to another server that serves resources written in Java. Otherwise I don't see why you need to setup a NodeJS application and another Spring application on the same server to work together serving certain resources.

Even if the combination make sense, using the 2 different technologies would mean that your server application will be running 2 different processes;

1. a Java process for your `springboot` application
2. a Node process for your `nodeJS running express`

Since each process will have its own memory space, this means that for both processes to communicate they will have to use the TCP/IP networking stack (http request). Where this and many other complicated considerations could be avoided, if you just go fully with 1 of the techs.

Comment: Yes, It does make sense. "Unless you are saying you are intending to build a NodeJS application to act as a proxy server to talk to another server that serves resources written in Java." - This is what I was thinking about. NodeJS could be just additional layer through which i can apply some additional stuff to requests. Probably, in the beginning, it will make a sense to build web services using Java, and just have Angular App talking to it, and not bother with NodeJS.  - Thanks

Comment: Yes. I won't be too bothered to complicate things. Pretty sure there will be stuff around in the `java` domain that can do similar things to what `express` can. Glad I have helped you in some ways. Will appreciate if you can click on the tick beside my answer to mark this as answered. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why question is closed, but actually you can use express as proxying middleware to prevent exposing your api server. For example if you use containers react app will have ability to access internal network api service through express with http proxy middleware and you do not need to anounce routes in nginx for example.